# In android, my drag listener won't work

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I set a touch listener and a drag listener at every view in a table:

```
view.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
view.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
```

My code for my drag listener and touch listener is pretty much the same. My touch listener works fine, but my drag listener won't even give the debug information for the first line.

```
class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
    public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Drag");
        ...
        return true;
    }
}
```

I'm using an AVD that I installed with Eclipse on Ubuntu, if that matters. Any idea what went wrong? Is there anything I could use instead? The drag listener only works for the later versions of android, so the must be some depreciated way of doing it, right?

Answer (score 0):

On which version of android are you running your app ?

the `OnDragListener` [Require API 11](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) (HoneyComb)